# Authorization header and apache_request_headers function

Tags: php, http-headers

I've been on a journey to getting [apache_request_headers()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) working on my server. I have upgraded to the latest stable of PHP 5.4 and changed my PHP handler to FastCGI as this allows you to run the apache_request_headers() function. I'd rather not run PHP as an apache module due to permission issues.

Everything works fine with my new set-up but the only issue is that apache_request_headers() does not seem to pick up the "Authorization" header which I require for my OAuth 2 server.

The header I am sending is:

```
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

However, if I send the following header (or anything other than 'Authorization'), it works:

```
X-Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Frustrating... Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Comment: What OS are you using? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and PHP 5.5.5-1+debphp.org~precise+2 (cli), but when I test for the existence of "apache_request_headers" I get bool(false) returned.

Comment: See my answer below :) Worked it out.

Comment: I think it's because I was using mod_fastcgi w/ php-fpm. It seems to be pretty well known that that function doesn't exist when using that setup. I also need to get Access-Control-Allow-Origin and other headers to work, but have had no such luck. I don't need "Authorization" in my case I'm afraid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some more digging I found the following. It removes the need for the apache_request_headers() altogether if you aren't using the FastCGI PHP handler or not running PHP as an apache module.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

On a separate note, another header I was needing was Content-Type which I was only able to get in the apache_request_headers() function. Might be helpful for someone :)

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE:%{HTTP:Content-Type}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, when using php with Fast CGI and FPM, the following is doing the trick:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ... # other configuration
    FastCgiExternalServer {other parameters} -pass-header Authorization
    ... # further configuration
</VirtualHost>
```

It removes the need for rewrite rule.
I found my solution to work when the RewriteRule solution did not work:
It may come from the apache I used being behind a haproxy, but the Authorization header was somehow "renamed" (by who/what?) `REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` instead of `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`.

Hope this helps.